# open collapsible div programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery mobile and I have collapsible div which I want to expand after ajax request.

```
<div id="collapsibleDiv"/>


function DisplayData() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.ajax({
            ...
             success: function (result) {
                $("#" + code).html(result);
                $.mobile.loading('hide');                    
                $("#collapsibleDiv").trigger('collapse');
             },
             error: ...
            });
        };
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to open div, cause this doesnt work

Comment: The what your code does? Nothing? Triggers an error? Eats your lunch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [api](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#method-expand), this will expand the div

```
    $( "#collapsibleDiv" ).collapsible( "expand" );
```